# Get Array of Object from within the JsonObject in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, loopback

I wanna get data from multiple tables using joins in node.js. I have written this query.

```
    Report.find({
  where: {id: data},
  include: {
    relation: 'reportSections',
    scope: {
      'fields': ['id', 'reportId', 'sectionId'],
      include: {
        relation: 'section',
        scope: {
          include: {
            relation: 'sectionFields',
            scope: {
              include: [{relation: 'reportMeta'},
                {relation: 'fields'}],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}, function(err, response) {

  console.log(response[0]);
  cb(null, Object.keys(response[0]));
});
```

As the result of this query I am getting this response.

```
[
      {
        "Name": "Dalton Patron",
        "id": 1,
        "reportSections": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "sectionId": 1,
            "reportId": 1,
            "section": {
              "label": "Personal Details",
              "id": 1,
              "sectionFields": [
                {
                  "label": "First Name",
                  "id": 1,
                  "sectionId": 1,
                  "fieldsId": 1,
                  "fields": {
                    "Type": "Text Field ",
                    "id": 1
                  },
                  "reportMeta": [
                    {
                      "Value": "Muhammad Naeem AKhtar",
                      "id": 1,
                      "sectionFieldId": 1
                    },
                    {
                      "Value": "sss",
                      "id": 2,
                      "sectionFieldId": 1
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "label": "Second Name",
                  "id": 2,
                  "sectionId": 1,
                  "fieldsId": 1,
                  "fields": {
                    "Type": "Text Field ",
                    "id": 1
                  },
                  "reportMeta": []
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I wanna get each each object present within the above json seperately. The problem which I am facing here is that if I wanna  get Name and Id property in seperate variable I am able to get that successfully but I am unable to get reportsections array. Can you please tell me that how I can Get it using Node.

If I get the object keys using:-

```
Object.keys(response[0]
```

It is returning:

```
[
  "__cachedRelations",
  "__data",
  "__dataSource",
  "__strict",
  "__persisted"
]
```

Can Please somebody let me know the solution about this in node js. Thanks

Comment: If `Object.keys` is returning that array, then `response` is not what you have posted. It is probably a wrapper object from some tool you're using.

Comment: What is your actual response? Normally in node.js, response.body give required result.

Comment: Actually I have written this in the api If I am calling the api from my client side I am getting the above mention response but within my api I am unable to access the properties that I am passing to this response.

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` give then?

Comment: It looks like you have a wrapper object holding the response data. The response data is probably in `__data` that probably has a get function for it.

Comment: console.log is giving this result:                                                                                                         { Name: 'Dalton Patron',
  id: 1,
  reportSections:
   List [ { id: 1, sectionId: 1, reportId: 1, section: [Object] } ] }

Comment: @RobertBrisita you are right can you please help me to get the reportsections? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your question giving details of what library you are using to make the request and receive data. An example request showing the code you are using will help others understand better.

Comment: I have editted the question please check it so that you have better understand what I want. Thanks

Comment: @RobertBrisita can you please let me know the solution for this. Thanks

Comment: I am assuming you are using loopback. Check out this documentation: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html#access-included-objects

Comment: @RobertBrisita thanks for your suggestion. Yup I am using loopback.